# If each row of $A$ has sum $s$, how to show that $s$ is an eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I set $b=[1,1,1,\ldots,1]$ and $A_1b=A_2b=\cdots=A_nb $ (in rows) and $Ab$ can be reduced to $[1,0,0,\ldots,0]$. But how do you find a way to prove s as an eigenvalue since we cannot guarantee $A$ is diagonal?

Comment: Multiply $A$ by your vector $b$ see what is the result

Comment: No reduction is required, just do the multiplication and see that you get $[s,s,\dots,s]^T$.